# Git stopped prompting for password

Tags: macos, git, command-line, ssh

I am using Git via command line on Mac OSX.

I have a remote repo called rwlive that I had been connecting to, making many successful pulls & pushes. Each time I did a pull or push, the command line prompted me for a password. No problems.

A few days ago, I started working on a different project on a different server. I was having some problems and may have added some things to Git to get it to work.

Then today when I tried to pull from the rwlive repo, it failed without prompting me for the password.

For example, I entered:

```
git pull rwlive master
```

The reponse:

```
Received disconnect from 50.116.75.129: 2: Too many authentication failures for rosa
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any ideas why it's no longer prompting me for the password? What can I do to force Git to prompt for password?

Comment: it's not prompting your because your account's been disabled for too many failed login attempts

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all:

> Too many authentication failures for rosa

It looks like you are "locked out": the Git repository server rejects your connection attempts without checking your password. It looks like a security feature to prevent brute-force attacks.

You need to contact the Git repository server administrators to unlock your account so that you can authenticate again.

Comment: I looked into that. We've checked with Hostgator and they insist no one is locked out. Also, the other two people using the same user have no problems.

Also, I switched to my PC and attempted a connection and it DID prompt for a password. 

I'm thinking it's something I may have changed or added to Git like the osx-keychain that may be supplying a wrong password.

Comment: Hmmm... This answer on another question might help, let me know: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6414234/641955